# to add .default or not?: dynamic imports in react router 3 for webpack code-splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

Recently I'm working on upgrading my project from webpack 3 (v. 3.3.0) to webpack 4 (v. 4.44.2). Compiling and building worked perfectly, but it turned out to render nothing on the screen.

After I compared the parameters passed to `RouterContext` between two projects of webpack 3 and of webpack 4, I narrowed down the root cause to dynamic imported components.

The following script is how I use react-router 3 (v. 3.0.5) `getComponent` to import component, which is workable before I upgrade to webpack 4:

```js
const loadRoute = callback => module => callback(null, module);

const forceToReload = (err) => {
  Logger.error(err);
  window.location.reload();
};

export default (loadRoute, forceToReload) => (
  <Route name="Subscribe" path={appUtils.getRoutePath('/sample')}
         getComponent={(location, callback) => import('./index.jsx').then(loadRoute(callback)).catch(forceToReload)}/>
);
```

Fortunately, after days of trials & errors, I finally made my project render correctly.
In webpack 4 version, I have to append `.default` to module in `loadRoute` as follows:

```js
const loadRoute = callback => module => callback(null, module.default);
```

### The Question is

Even though the problem is solved, I still wonder if someone can provide an explanation about when to add `.default`. 
 Does webpack 4 compile differently on dynamic import? Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I needed to convert from require.ensure to import() because webpack 5 kicked it out. As for default, this might be a react-router thing. I always added it to my my require.ensure statements when getting the component.

Comment: Actually from the webpack docu: The reason we need default is that since webpack 4, when importing a CommonJS module, the import will no longer resolve to the value of module.exports, it will instead create an artificial namespace object for the CommonJS module. and referencing this article: https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-import-and-commonjs-d619d626b655 And I see you found that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of research, I finally found the answer to my question, hoping I can somehow help those with the same question in the future.

Webpack official website ([Code-Splitting: Dynamic Import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)) has a description as follows:

> The reason we need default is that since webpack 4, when importing a CommonJS module, the import will no longer resolve to the value of module.exports, it will instead create an artificial namespace object for the CommonJS module.

Out of curiosity, I did some experiment logging out things I dynamic imports:

```js
// exportObject.js
export default {a: 1, b: 2};
export const c = 3;

// exportString.js
export default "TEST_STRING";

// exportComponent.js
import React, {Component} from "react";
export default class exportComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;
  }
}

// exportFunction.js
export default () => ({a: 1, b: 2});
```

```js
// index.js
componentDidMount() {
 import('./exportObject').then(module => {
    console.group('Object');
    console.warn('module', module);
    console.warn('module.a:', module.a);
    console.warn('module.b:', module.b);
    console.warn('module.default', module.default);
    console.warn('module.c', module.c);
    console.groupEnd();
  });

  import('./exportString').then(module => {
    console.group('String');
    console.warn('module', module);
    console.warn('module.default', module.default);
    console.groupEnd();
  });

  import('./exportComponent').then(module => {
    console.group('Component');
    console.warn('module', module);
    console.warn('module.default', module.default);
    console.groupEnd();
  });

  import('./exportFunction').then(module => {
    console.group('Function');
    try {
      console.warn('module()', module());
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('module()', e);
    }
    try {
      console.warn('module.default()', module.default());
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn('module.default()', e);
    }
    console.groupEnd();
  });
}
```

This is the result from Webpack 3 Project:

[image]

While from Webpack 4 Project:

[image]

As you can see, non-objects have different results. This finding matches the description of this [article](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-import-and-commonjs-d619d626b655) (which is provided by webpack official)

> It’s not that problematic when exporting an object. But you’ll get into trouble when using module.exports with non-objects.

I use `export default` in my code rather than `module.exports`, then why I still got the result?
Actually, Babel@6 will do the transform as below: ([reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports))

> Babel@6 transforms the following file
>
> ```js
> export default 'foo'
> ```
>
> into
>
> ```js
> 'use strict';
> Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
>   value: true
> });
> exports.default = 'foo';
> ```

Now, things are crystal clear.

The packages I used was:

```
node: 11.15.0

babel-core: "^6.23.1",
babel-loader: "7.1.4",
webpack: "4.44.2",
webpack-cli: "^4.2.0",
```